# Apollo type defs ignored

Tags: javascript, apollo, apollo-client

I've made a basic implementation of `ApolloClient`:

```
const gqlClient = new ApolloClient({
    connectToDevTools: true,
    link: new HttpLink({
        uri: "/api",
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    resolvers: {
        Group: {
            icon: () => "noIcon",
        },
    },
    typeDefs: gql`
        extend type Group {
            icon: String!
        }
    `,
});
```

The only fancy thing is the one resolver and type def - both of which are to support an `icon` field for groups (an upcoming feature).

I then try to query the server with the following:

```
gqlClient.query({
    query: gql`{
        groups {
            name
            icon
        }
    }`,
})
    .then(console.log);
```

and get a big 'ol error:

```
bundle.esm.js:63 Uncaught (in promise) Error: GraphQL error: Cannot query field `icon' on type `Group'.
    at new ApolloError (bundle.esm.js:63)
    at bundle.esm.js:1247
    at bundle.esm.js:1559
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at bundle.esm.js:1557
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at QueryManager../node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.esm.js.QueryManager.broadcastQueries (bundle.esm.js:1555)
    at bundle.esm.js:1646
    at Object.next (Observable.js:322)
    at notifySubscription (Observable.js:135)
```

Running the same query without asking for `icon` works perfectly.  I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.  **How can I mock `icon` and fix this error?**

I'm only running Apollo Client - do I need to run Apollo Server to get all of the features?  The outgoing request doesn't seem to have any of my type def information, so I'm not sure how the having Apollo server would make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Handling @client fields with resolvers](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/local-state/#handling-client-fields-with-resolvers)

```
gqlClient.query({
    query: gql`
        {
            groups {
                name
                icon @client
            }
        }
    `,
});
```